# What the unexpected behavior Observable RxJS with async functions and toPromise?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs6

When i use only subscribe-method, it works truthy, but with this code - i don't understand the result.

```
const Observable = require("rxjs").Observable;
let i = 0;
const x = new Observable((o) => {
    setInterval(() => o.next(++i), 1000);
});

(async () => {
    while (true) {
        try {
            console.log("loop");
            console.log("value", await x.toPromise());
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
})();
x.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log("subscribe", value);
});
```

This code result is:

```
loop
subscribe 2
subscribe 4
subscribe 6
subscribe 8
subscribe 10
subscribe 12
subscribe 14
```

What's happened?

It works same with this variant of using toPromise

```
function a() {
    x.toPromise().then((value) => {
        console.log("promise", value);
        a();
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log("error", value);
    });
}
a();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toPromise()` is executed on an Observable on its completion. Since your observable is never actually completed, it does not execute. Use [`take(1)`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html) to force it to emit value before the completion of the observable.

```js
const Observable = require("rxjs").Observable;
let i = 0;
const x = new Observable((o) => {
    setInterval(() => o.next(++i), 1000);
});

(async () => {
    while (true) {
        try {
            console.log("loop");
            console.log("value", await x.take(1).toPromise());//here
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
})();
x.subscribe((value) => {
    console.log("subscribe", value);
});
```

Output:

```
loop
subscribe 2
value 1
loop
subscribe 4
value 5
loop
subscribe 7
value 9
loop
subscribe 11
value 14
```

As for the values:

`take()` will complete once atleast one value is emitted regardless of whether the source observable completes. So it really depends on what value the observable is emitting the next time the `toPromise()` is called

Comment: `take()` will complete regardless of whether source observable completes. So it really depends on what value the observable is emitting the next time the `toPromise` is called

Comment: @arvitaly »Not obvious« is something you can counter by reading the documentation. It describes clearly how it behaves.

Comment: @SurajRao No, `source.take(1)` is not guaranteed to complete. It only completes if source emits at least once. Also, it doesn't complete if the source errors before emission.